# Error during boot.:encrypted source does not exist

Tags: boot, busybox

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have access to busybox after exit it says:

```
/Scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 218: not found.     
        ALERT! encrypted source device uuid=longstring Does not exist, can't unlock nvme0n1p3_crypt.
Check cryptops=source=bootarg= /processor/cmdline
Or missing modules, devices: cat /processor/modules; ls /devices
Dropping to shell
BusyBox
```

e.t.c.

I also booted from usb but gparted can't see my hard drive?

I don't mind losing my data as it's backed up I just need to work.

Answer (score 3):

Had a very similar issue after an update of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS13 (2020).
Searched for hours, the solution was actually easy.

reboot and go to BIOS using "fn and F2"
BIOS > System Configuration > Sata Operation > switch to "AHCI" from "RAID On"

For some reason, this BIOS setting was switched.

Comment: just wanted to say that you saved my life, this happened to me after battery replacement

Comment: I also have a dell XPS. i hadnt used the laptop in about a year, so i suspect the internal battery died so the BIOS settings were lost, or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

The result message is basically "something went wrong you should check out these possible investigation options".  Really the problem is that `nvme0n1p3_crypt` does not exist, or really it was never loaded. (You can see this from the [cryptroot executable](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/blob/master/debian/initramfs/scripts/local-top/cryptroot)

- This configuration can be seen by: `cat /etc/crypttab`.
- Just to corroborate what is happening by: `ls /dev/`

The problem is that your NVMe drive was never loaded. The problem is usually the bios configuration which attempts to allow RAID drive configurations to load. Turn off RAID drive and switch to AHCI.

- [BIOS versus UEFI](https://forums.crucial.com/t5/Suggestion-Box/IDE-vs-AHCI-vs-RAID-MBR-vs-GPT-BIOS-vs-UEFI-booting-and-other/td-p/183260)
- aoe
- [Capture your boot configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info)
- [ArchLinux suggestion to turn off](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=239717)
- [What UEFI really is and how to dual boot install with it](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [Dual boot configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows)